# Getting MMDDYYYY format in vb script

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I have a source file called `venkat_file`. I need to archive the file into an archive folder, whilst appending the file to this format, `venkat_file_MMDDYYY`. If the month and date values are less than 10 I wanted to archive the file with specific values,

Example before: `venkat_file`, example date `4/26/2013`, now I need to archive the file so it looks like this: `venkat_file_04262013`, instead of `venkat_file_4262013`.

Thanks in advance,

Venkat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the date using the following

```
Dim ThisDate as string
'
ThisDate = format(now.month,"00") &  format(now.day,"00") & format(now.year,"0000")
```

## Update

As Raybiss pointed out its not vbscript.
So i've put the vbscript below.

```
<script type="text/vbscript" id="ArchiveFile">
' <!--
Function GetNewArchiveFilename(ThisFile)
'
Dim ThisDay, ThisMonth, ThisYear
Dim ThisFName
'
  ThisDay = day(date)
  ThisMonth = month(date)
  ThisYear = year(date)
  ThisFName = Left(Thisfile, len(thisfile)-4) & FormatNumber(Thisday,0,-1) & formatnumber(Thismonth,0,-1) & formatnumber(thisyear,0,0,0,0) & right(thisfile,4)
  'msgbox(thisfname)
  return thisfname
'
End Function
' -->
</script>
```

Comment: This would be VB/VBA but not VBScript

Answer (score 2):

You could have a function like this one:

```
Function FormatNum(n, totalDigits) 
  If totalDigits > Len(n) Then 
      FormatNum = String(totalDigits - Len(n),"0") & n 
  Else 
      FormatNum = n 
  End if 
End Function
```

And use it like that:

```
s = FormatNum(Month(Date()) , 2) & _
    FormatNum(Day(Date()), 2) & _
    Year(Date())
```